Как восстановить файлы проекта после редеплоя на Railway.app, если они не сохранены в GitHub?
У меня есть проект на GitHub, к которому подключена тестовая версия Railway.app. У меня возник вопрос: если я редеплоил проект в Railway.app, но сам файлы не сохранил, есть ли возможность скачать из Railway.app то, что было развернуто? Потому что в GitHub то, что работает в Railway, не сохранилось после редеплоя
